# How can I do sort an HTML table by header on web application mvc 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html

I need help to sort the Id column. I researched how to sort the tables by the header, but could not find how to order tables in mvc, please help me to sort this table by header. I just need to sort the column ID

All variables are in Models,
  this is my code on Controller:

```
        List<PedidosPostosModel> lista = new List<PedidosPostosModel>();

        PedidosPostosModel p1 = new PedidosPostosModel();
        p1.ID = 123;
        p1.DataPedido = DateTime.Now;
        p1.DataResposta = new DateTime(2015, 01, 15);
        p1.DataRecolha = new DateTime(2015, 01, 16);
        p1.Estado = "Executado";
        p1.Tipo = "Recolha";
        p1.Motorista = "13";
        lista.Add(p1);

        PedidosPostosModel p2 = new PedidosPostosModel();
        p2.ID = 13;
        p2.DataPedido = DateTime.Now;
        p2.DataResposta = new DateTime(2015, 01, 15);
        p2.DataRecolha = new DateTime(2015, 01, 16);
        p2.Estado = "Aceite";
        p2.Tipo = "Espera";
        p2.Motorista = "2";
        lista.Add(p2);

        PedidosPostosModel p3 = new PedidosPostosModel();
        p3.ID = 1;
        p3.DataPedido = DateTime.Now;
        p3.DataResposta = new DateTime(2015, 01, 15);
        p3.DataRecolha = new DateTime(2015, 01, 16);
        p3.Estado = "Anulado";
        p3.Tipo = "Material";
        p3.Motorista = "4";
        lista.Add(p3);

        PedidosPostosModel p4 = new PedidosPostosModel();
        p4.ID = 3;
        p4.DataPedido = DateTime.Now;
        p4.DataResposta = new DateTime(2015, 01, 15);
        p4.DataRecolha = new DateTime(2015, 01, 16);
        p4.Estado = "Executado";
        p4.Tipo = "Material";
        p4.Motorista = "8";
        lista.Add(p4);

        PedidosPostosModel p5 = new PedidosPostosModel();
        p5.ID = 123;
        p5.DataPedido = DateTime.Now;
        p5.DataResposta = new DateTime(2015, 01, 15);
        p5.DataRecolha = new DateTime(2015, 01, 16);
        p5.Estado = "Aceite";
        p5.Tipo = "Recolha";
        p5.Motorista = "9";
        lista.Add(p5);

        return View(lista);
```

This is my table in Views:

```
d="myTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0">
              <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ID)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DataPedido)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DataResposta)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DataRecolha)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Estado)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Tipo)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Motorista)
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @item.ID
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @item.DataPedido
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @item.DataResposta
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @item.DataRecolha
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @item.Estado
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @item.Tipo
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @item.Motorista
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </table>
```

Comment: Do you want to sort when the page initially loaded or when user click on Id column?

Comment: @SBirthare, Thanks for replying, but It doesn't work.. I want to sort when user click on the Id column.

Comment: In that case i am afraid you will have to implement functionality to send column name to server and reload grid with sorted data. There are few free grids available which has inbuilt functionality, try that if you want to.

Comment: Capture column click event, send ajax request to server, server sort data with column and send back. Reload grid with data.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
lista.Add(p5);
lista.OrderByDescending(x=>x.ID);
//or 
lista.OrderBy(x=>x.ID); 
return View(lista);
```